# HTML Button reloading current page

Tags: javascript, html

I have many buttons on the webpage that are working correct, but some of the buttons are not responding the same way.

```js
function Function() {
    var x = new Date().toLocaleString();
    document.getElementById("M_Date").innerHTML = x;
      
    var M_Submit  = document.getElementById("M_Submit");
    var M_Yes  = document.getElementById("M_Yes ");
      
    M_Submit.style.display = "none";
    M_Yes.style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="Function(); return false;">Complete</button>
```

I have also tried copying a button that is working and pasting it in the same location and replacing the function for that spot.
I have also change the Function name to something else and same result.

Comment: Could we see the code that you're referring to?

Comment: Also I have pulled up the developer tools and ran the Function(), and it pass with out error and loads the next section like its suppose to.

Comment: Without any other information, it's hard to tell what you want to do

Comment: Provide a working code snippet. See also all discussions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800720/problem-with-javascript-return-false-is-not-working) SO question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button is likely in a form, and the browser is expecting it to act as a "Submit" button.   Add the attribute type="button" to the button code like this

`<button type="button">`

Adding the type here should prevent the page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "return false" statement in the html button so that it looks like this: 
    < button onclick="Function()" >Complete< /button >