# JavaScript confirm cancel button still posting

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

Cancel button on the confirm dialog still causing post back and calling server side button event.

```
   <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" CssClass="CommandButton" Width="110px" OnClientClick="confirmPayment();" UseSubmitBehavior="false"
                            Text="Submit Payment" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"></asp:Button>


function confirmPayment() {
                var isOkay = confirm("Confirm Payment?");

                if (isOkay) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
```

I tried to debug my code and i can see it is returning false and then doing post back. Not sure if there is something wrong with my code?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Modern browsers disregard the return value from the client-side `onclick` event-handler, instead you need to pass the ambient `event` object into your `confirmPayment` function and then call `event.preventDefault()` (and possibly `stopPropagation()` too, depending on what mess of client-side scripts you have in your page because you're using WebControls).

Comment: But a better idea is **TO NOT USE WEBFORMS IN 2020**. It's an awful, atrocious and misguided platform that Microsoft themselves killed-off back in 2008: **that was 12 years ago**. There is no excuse for using it today.

Comment: @Dai I concur with your assessment of WebForms, but I don't think modern browsers "disregard the return value from the client-side `onclick` event-handler". I think the OP could just as easily put `OnClientClick="return confirmPayment();"` and get the functionality desired...

Comment: i think i am missing return, i will try OnClientClick="return confirmPayment();" Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write `return confirmPayment` in `OnClientClick`
Try this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" CssClass="CommandButton" Width="110px" OnClientClick="return confirmPayment();" UseSubmitBehavior="false" Text="Submit Payment" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"></asp:Button>
```

Comment: Yes, it would work, but it won't when we move the code outside the submit button. For that, this should to be code. In my case, I need to disable and enable submit button to prevent double submit.:


    <script type="text/javascript">
        function confirmSubmit(event) {

            if (!confirm('Are you certain you want to lodge this form ?')) {
                event.disabled = false;

                event.preventDefault();
                stopPropagation();

                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    </script>

Comment: I have posted my answer here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800720/problem-with-javascript-return-false-is-not-working

Answer (score 0):

You need to accept the `event` object in the click handler, and use `preventDefault`:

```
function confirmPayment(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: do i need to pass this as a parameter ? OnClientClick="confirmPayment(this);

Comment: i will test $('#btnSubmit').on('click',function(e){

Comment: @user1263981 in HTML it will look like this (part of your code): `...OnClientClick="confirmPayment(event);"...`, because `event` value is visible inside event handlers